# Is there a way to define a Typescript interface with "pre-defined" keys as well as arbitrary keys?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to define an interface with keys that will always be there (`bar` and `baz`) and also preserve the possibility of having other arbitrary keys as well.

Example of an object that I'm trying to write an interface for:

```json
{ 
  "bar": "ABC", 
  "baz": 10, 
  "something-something": true 
}
```

Example of a desired interface (which doesn't really work):

```js
interface Foo {
  // pre-defined keys
  bar: string;
  baz: number;

  // other arbitrary keys
  [key: string]: boolean;
}
```

The error I'm getting for the above interface:

> TS2411: Property 'foo' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'boolean'.

Rewriting the interface into a `type` and separating "mandatory" keys from the "arbitrary" ones doesn't work either:

```js
type Foo2 = {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
} & { [key: string]: boolean };
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: There's no good way to say "all properties *except* `foo` and `bar` will be of type `boolean`".  See the linked question/answers for the various approaches and workarounds.  Your `Foo2` type works for some use cases but not all.